# How feature map in Keras ConvNet represent features?

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I know that it might be a dumb question, but I searched everywhere for an answer but I could not get.

Okay first properly explaining my question,

When I was learning CNN I was told that kernels or filters or activation map represent a feature of image. 
To be specific, assume a cat image identification, a feature map would represent a "whiskers" 
and in images which the activation of this feature map would be high it is inferred as whisker is present in image and so the image is a cat. (Correct me if I am wrong)

Well now when I made a Keras ConvNet I save the model
 and then loaded the model and 
 saved all the filters to png images.
 What I saw was 3x3 px images where each each pixel was of different colour (green, blue or their various variants and so on)

So how these 3x3px random colour pattern images of kernels represent in any way the "whisker" or any other feature of cat?

Or how could I know which png images is which feature ie which is whisker detector filter etc?

I am asking this because I might be asked in oral examination by teacher.

Sorry for the length of answer (but I had to make it so to explain properly)

Comment: Why -1 for the question, tell me I won't repeat the mistake next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a further look into how convolutional neural networks operate: the main topic being the convolution itself. The convolution occurs with the input image and filters/kernels to produce feature maps. A feature map is what may highlight important features.

The filters/kernels do not know anything of the input data so when you save these you are only going to see psuedo-random images.

Put simply, where * is the convolution operator,

> input_image * filter = feature map

What you want to save, if you want to vizualise what is occuring during convolution, are the feature maps. [This website](https://towardsdatascience.com/visualizing-intermediate-activation-in-convolutional-neural-networks-with-keras-260b36d60d0) gives a very detailed account on how to do so, and it is the method I have used in the past.

Comment: okay your statement `filters do not know anything of input data, they are just pseudo-random` means I was wrong about `feature represent a whisker` in my question. `filters are default initialised by Keras and adjusted accordingly to learning images` is the correct statement ?